# Passportjs LocalStartegy is not called

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

i'm following a tutorial on nodejs and expressjs with projects, the project is a user login/registeration/logout system. i'm stuck on the login with passportjs, the LocalStartegy object is not called on execution even though everything is right since i removed it and logged a message; i know its not called because it doesn't log anything

this is the code

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
   });
});

//local startegy
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
usernameField: 'login',
passwordField: 'password'
},

function(username, password,done){
    console.log('local startegy called!');
    User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if(!user){
            console.log('Unknown User');
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
        }

        User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function (err, isMatch) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if(isMatch){
                return done(null, user);
            }else{
                console.log('Invalid password');
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
            }
        });
    });
}
));

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {failureRedirect: 
'/users/login', failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password'}), function(req, res){
//runs if the local startegy comes back true
console.log('Authentication successfull...');
req.flash('success', 'You are logged in');
res.redirect('/');
});
```

and this is my form

```
extends layout

block content
    h1 Login
    p Login if you are already a member
    form(method='post', action='/users/login', multipart='urlencoded')
    .form-group
        label Username
        input.form-control(name='username', type='text', 
 placeholder='username')
    .form-group
        label Password
        input.form-control(name='password', type='password', 
 placeholder='password')
    input.btn.btn-default(name='submit', type='submit', value='login')
```

Comment: Your form submits to `/users/login` instead of `/login`. Your form field for `username` is called `username` but in your `passport` config you expect it to be called `login`.

Comment: thank you so much you have relieved a pain